# Responsive overlapping images

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a home page with a background-image (in a div) and several clickable areas in this image which bring to other pages of the site. This sections are anchors which change the image of their area on mouse hover. All images are .svg and the anchors are in absolute position. This is my problem: when I reduce the window, the image in background adapts its-self to the window, but the anchors do not and stay on their position, but I would like them to adapt to the window too. I tried with max-width and min-width but I did not solve the problem, probably because they are in absolute position. There is a way to obtain a resize and adaptation of the anchors to the image in background? I use HTML and CSS, but I don't know Javascript. This is my code:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                a:hover {
                    background-image: url('../immaginisito/living_Tavola disegno 1.svg'); background-size:cover;
                }
                a:active {
                    background-image: url('../immaginisito/living_Tavola disegno 1.svg'); background-size:cover;
                }
                .background {
                    overflow:visible;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

               <div class='background' style="position:relative; height:600px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url('../immaginisito/Loft_Vierre_Tavola disegno 1.svg'); background-size:cover;">
                <a id="a" onclick="changeOpacity('a')" style="position:absolute; top:114px; left:4px; width:74px; height:40px;" title="#f" alt="#f" href="#f" target="_self"></a>
                <a id="b" onclick="changeOpacity('b')" style="position:absolute; top:85px; left:163px; width:114px; height:48px;" title="aa" alt="aa" href="#a" target="_self"></a>
                <a id="c" onclick="changeOpacity('c')" style="position:absolute; top:180px; left:60px; width:88px; height:30px;" title="#b" alt="#b" href="#b" target="_self"></a>
                <a id="d" onclick="changeOpacity('d')" style="position:absolute; top:132px; left:313px; width:118px; height:65px;" title="#c" alt="#c" href="#c" target="_self"></a>
                <a id="e" onclick="changeOpacity('e')" style="position:absolute; top:208px; left:762px; width:133px; height:300px;" title="#e" alt="#e" href="#e" target="_self"></a>
            </div>
        </body>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </html>
    <script>
     function changeOpacity(id) {
         document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = "url('../immaginisito/living_Tavola disegno 1.svg')";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Leelo, could you write some of your code?

Comment: Hi, this is my code:

Answer (score 0):

use the percentages in anchors instead of pixels to keep anchors in the same position after resizing the window.for example top: 22% instead of 50px or something.

Answer (score 0):

try to use display:grid feature instead of position to adjust the responsive screen
so remove position:absolute from child div and positon:relative from parent div and put that for the parent div

```
.background{
display:grid
grid-template-row:1fr 1fr;
grid-template-column:1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: I tried to put display grid into background's css eliminating positions, but all elements display following the html flow